# Interpretation of living dangerously

Tags: ethics, nietzsche

Continuing discussion of [Master morality vs slave morality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101423/master-morality-vs-slave-morality/101453#101453)
My second question is how would you interpret when Friedrich Nietzsche say "live dangerously". Is it to live risky lives even its immoral ?

Answer (score 1):

I think when Nietzsche advocates to "live dangerously," he is not promoting immoral or unethical behavior. Rather, he is encouraging people to question conventional ways of thinking, push boundaries, embrace life's challenges and struggles etc. I think his idea is about several things basically..

- a call to break free from herd mentality and mediocrity. Nietzsche despised passive nihilism and living reactively. "Living dangerously" means having the courage to think independently and authentically.
- an exhortation to be willing to take risks and get outside one's comfort zone. Instead of complacency, view life as an adventure and say "yes" to its trials and tribulations.
- harnessing one's full power and potential. Be bold and assertive, strive for excellence, embrace your instincts and willpower. Push yourself to the limits.
- Dionysian celebration of passion, creativity, and embracing one's nature fully. Move with vigor rather than stagnate.

So in essence, "living dangerously" is primarily an attitude - one of courage, autonomy and creativity in the face of life's challenges.